# English word meaning the time point at which a decision has been made

Tags: word-request

Is there an English word to describe the points in time when decisions have been made  (especially those with far-reaching consequences)? A bit like tipping point. But *choice point* or *decision point* sound weird to me...

Comment: I think "decision point" might be OK. Curious ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decision+point&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdecision%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdecision%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDecision%20Point%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDECISION%20POINT%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDecision%20point%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Could be "resolution juncture"...

Answer (score 1):

"A *critical* point" and a *turning* point can be used. [Critical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical) has the following meaning in Merriam-Webster:

**of, relating to, or being a turning point or specially important juncture :** as (1):  relating to or being the stage of a disease at which an abrupt change for better or worse may be expected; also:  being or relating to an illness or condition involving danger of death   (2):  **relating to or being a state in which or a measurement or point at which some quality, property, or phenomenon suffers a definite change**

Comment: Same as "tipping point" as OP states.  It doesn't specifically mean that *a decision* was made.  It only defines "something important", like all other terms.

Answer (score 0):

**D-Day**

If you're talking about a day, then the secondary meaning of *D-Day* would fit the bill:

> The day on which an important operation is to begin or a change to take effect

This is a secondary idiomatic meaning, and you should be aware of the first literal meaning before using the word, which is available here:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/D-Day?q=d-day

Comment: Nah.  The decision to start an operation on a certain day (which the military call "D-day") or hour (which would be the "H-hour") is usually made on a different day.

Comment: D-Day as an idiom is merely the critical day on which something happens. If you had to make an important decision on 25 December, then 25 December would be D-Day for that decision.

Comment: The point (which you may be missing) in time when that certain day is set **and** gets the designation of "the D-day", *always* precedes that day.  If you **plan** to make a certain decision on Nth of Nber, then the Nth of Nber becomes "the D-day", but what do you call that day on which you decided that the Nth of Nber shall be your D-day?

Comment: You can always trace your important events to a single moment in time, when the decision is spontaneous, unplanned.  What do you call that moment?

Comment: The question is in the past tense. The decision has already been made. And the day on which that decision was made was D-Day for that decision.

Comment: Yeah... No.  D-day, H-hour, T-time, are all set at some point ***in advance***.  That's the point that you're missing, I think.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't agree with you on using D-day. The dictionary clearly states "*is to*" begin which *clearly indicates* **a future event**. When you refer to the *past* D-day on which a certain military operation started in Word Wor II, you refer to the **historically important day**.